# jQuery display div after 6 characters entered into input field

Tags: jquery, regex

I would usually include a decent amount of code along with what I have tried, but for this one I don't really know where to begin.

To cut a long story short, what I need is to do display a `<div>` (or any other element) after 6 numbers have been entered in an `<input>` field, I also need to trim the white space so if someone enters 2 spaces (or 2 letters) the `<div>` wont display until they have entered 6 numbers.

I know how to do everything else I'm just not sure how to check if the input contains 6 numbers, stripping every other character.

I'm guessing I need some sort of regex?!?

If anyone can give me a nudge in the right direction I can update the question with more info once I've tried something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
   var len = this.value.match(/\d/g).length;
   if (len === 6) {
       // do something
   } 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZY4cf/

Comment: You can even omit the $.trim() because "white space" doesn't match \d anyway